# Comparing objects inside mapped array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects: this array has another array inside of it, with a list of objects with key, value pairs of users. I need to map this array into a list and ,if an user has the same name and last name, make sure it gets mapped with both locations under it. How can I do this? My first approach was comparing indexes, but this didn´t work. I also found a helper function to compare values inside array, but I can´t seem to integrate it into the mapping function. Any ideas?

Array:

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
               "name": "John",
               "last-name": "Edmus",
               "location": "USA"
            },
           {
                "name": "John",
               "last-name": "Edmus",
               "location": "California"
            },
           {
               "name": "Jane",
               "last-name": "Edmus"
               "location": "USA"
            }
        ]
    },

]
```

Ideal output:

```
<ul>
<li>"John Edmus, location: USA and California"</li>
<li> "Jane Edmus, location: USA"</li>
<ul>
```

What I tried so far

```
mapArray= () =>{
return test.map(i =>
i.users.map(user =>
<ul>{users.map.user.name.index + users.map.user.last-name.index === users.map.user.name.index + users.map.user.last-name.index + 2 : <li> {user.name} {user.last-name}</li>))}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Can you add to the question itself the helper function you found, and how you tried to integrate it in your code (with error/unexpected result it produces), so that your question is not a code writing request?

Comment: I´ll update the question

Comment: Updated question

Comment: will the outer array have multiple objects with inner arrays that could have the same person? in other words, will there be a chance a person could be found in multiple objects of the outer array?

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility but not very likely.

Comment: If I can get the users inside "users" to match that´s good enough for me

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts with your data: there are objects in your array that should be merged, but aren't. Let's fix this first.

### What makes a duplicate?

Let's first define what we consider duplicates. To do so, we'll define a `hash` function that outputs a unique string per user. You'll see why in a minute.

```
User.hash = user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
```

```js
// Here, we define our client-side user
const User = (firstName, lastName, locations) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  locations
});

// This defines what makes a user unique
User.hash = user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;

// A helper to easily map the users from our source data
// to client-side users
User.fromServerData = (userData) => User(
  userData.name, userData["last-name"], [userData.location]
);

// Use our User logic on your data
const data = [{users:[{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"},{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"California"},{name:"Jane","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"}]}];
const users = data[0].users.map(User.fromServerData);

// Log a list of user hashes
console.log(users.map(User.hash));
```

As you can see from the console log, we have a duplicate user!

### Finding the duplicates

Finding the duplicates is now a matter of grouping by hash. To do so, I'll define a quick `groupBy` helper. If you want to know how this helper works, you can google `js groupBy` or have a look at library implementations like underscore or ramda.

```js
const User = (firstName, lastName, locations) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  locations
});

User.hash = user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
User.fromServerData = (userData) => User(
  userData.name, userData["last-name"], [userData.location]
);

const data = [{users:[{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"},{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"California"},{name:"Jane","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"}]}];
const users = data[0].users.map(User.fromServerData);

console.log(groupBy(User.hash, users));

// Utils
function groupBy(getKey, xs) { return xs
  .map(x => [getKey(x), x])
  .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, {
      [k]: (acc[k] || []).concat(v)
  }), {});
}
```

**Now, we have our two Johns neatly grouped in an array.**

### Getting rid of the duplicattes

All that's left is to merge the duplicates. Like the `hash` method, we'll separate the logic:

```
User.merge = (userA, userB) => User(
  userB.firstName, 
  userB.lastName, 
  [ ...userA.locations, ...userB.locations ]
);
```

With this function, we can merge any list of duplicate users with a `reduce`:

```
const mergedUsers = duplicateUsers.reduce(User.merge);
```

*Note that you can use `reduce` without a seed, but it will break if you ever pass it an empty array. In the snippet below, we know for sure there will never be an empty array. I've included an empty user as a seed anyway, in case you ever reuse it someplace else.*

```js
const User = (firstName, lastName, locations) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  locations
});

User.hash = user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
User.merge = (userA, userB) => User(
  userB.firstName, 
  userB.lastName, 
  [...userA.locations, ...userB.locations]
);
User.empty = () => User(null, null, []);

User.fromServerData = (userData) => User(
  userData.name, userData["last-name"], [userData.location]
);

// Use our User logic on your data
const data = [{users:[{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"},{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"California"},{name:"Jane","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"}]}];
const users = data[0].users.map(User.fromServerData);

console.log(
  Object
    .values(groupBy(User.hash, users))
    .map(duplicates => duplicates
      .reduce(User.merge, User.empty())
    )
);


// Utils
function groupBy(getKey, xs) {
  return xs
    .map(x => [getKey(x), x])
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, {
        [k]: (acc[k] || []).concat(v)
    }), {});
};
```

### Making the most of our improved data

Now that the data is sorted out, we can render to a list without any custom logic:

```
User.render = ({ firstName, lastName, locations }) => 
  `<li>
    ${firstName} ${lastName} (${locations.join(" and ")}) 
   </li>`;

const view = `
  <ul>
    ${users.map(User.render).join("")}
  </ul>`;
```

```js
const User = (firstName, lastName, locations) => ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  locations
});

User.hash = user => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
User.merge = (userA, userB) => User(
  userB.firstName, 
  userB.lastName, 
  [...userA.locations, ...userB.locations]
);
User.empty = () => User(null, null, []);
User.render = user => `<li>
  ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} 
  (${user.locations.join(" and ")}) </li>`;

User.fromServerData = (userData) => User(
  userData.name, userData["last-name"], [userData.location]
);

const data = [{users:[{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"},{name:"John","last-name":"Edmus",location:"California"},{name:"Jane","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"}]}];

const userGroups = groupBy(
  User.hash,  
  data[0].users.map(User.fromServerData)
);

const users = Object.values(userGroups)
  .map(duplicates => duplicates
    .reduce(User.merge, User.empty())
  );

const view = `<ul>${users.map(User.render).join("")}</ul>`;
document.querySelector(".app").innerHTML = view;

// Utils
function groupBy(getKey, xs) {
  return xs
    .map(x => [getKey(x), x])
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, {
        [k]: (acc[k] || []).concat(v)
    }), {});
};
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too big for a comment
Maybe this code can help:

```
var json = '[{"users": [{"name": "John","last_name": "Edmus","location": "USA"},{"name": "John","last_name": "Edmus","location": "California"},{"name": "Jane","last_name": "Edmus","location": "USA"}]}]';

var to_array = JSON.parse(json);
var array_tmp = Array();

for(var item in to_array[0].users) {
    var element = to_array[0].users[item];
    var key = element.name +" "+ element.last_name;

    if( typeof array_tmp[key] !== "undefined" ) {
        array_tmp[key] += " and "+ element.location;    
    }
    else {
        array_tmp[key] = element.location;  
    }
}

console.log(array_tmp);
```

The output will be:

```
[John Edmus: "USA and California", Jane Edmus: "USA"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to map through all of the values inside "json" (I just pasted a copy of the array, not the entire thing)